# How to find the words that start with capital letters and its number in sentence?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I find the words that start with a capital and its number in sentence?

For example:

input:

`The Persian League is the largest sport event dedicated to the deprived areas of Iran. The Persian League promotes peace and friendship.  This video was captured by one of our heroes who wishes peace.`

output:

```
2:Persian
3:League
15:Iran
17:Persian
18:League
```

Comment: You have added the `python` tag, but you have added no code to your question.

Comment: Why isn't `The` and `This` included in the output? [ask]

Comment: the first words in sentence is not important

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
a = 'The Persian League is the largest sport event dedicated to the deprived areas of Iran. The Persian League promotes peace and friendship. This video was captured by one of our heroes who wishes peace.'
a = a.split(' ')

for index, key in enumerate(a):
    if key[0].isupper() and index != 0 and a[index-1][-1] != '.':
        print(index+1, key)
```

Comment: This would include the first words in the sentences which are "not important"

Comment: Its still incorrect, it only ignores the first word, not the first word per sentence

Comment: if i dont want to find the first words of each sentences . what shall i do ?
for example in my sting , there is 2 sentence

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it worked.

```python
string = "The Persian League is the largest sport event dedicated to the deprived areas of Iran. The Persian League promotes peace and friendship. This video was captured by one of our heroes who wishes peace."

count = 1

for word in string.split():
    if word[0].isupper() == True:
        print(str(count) + ":" + word)
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The short and beautiful solution.

```
words = list(map(lambda x: x.split(' ')[1:], input().split('. ')))
words = [i for g in words for i in g]
print(words)
for ind, word in enumerate(words):
    if word[0].isupper():
        print(f'{ind + 2}:{word}')
```